# Why am I unable to route to my API backend with Traefik

Tags: docker, traefik

I had two container frontend (nginx :80) and backend (nodejs :3000).
I'm trying to redirect all path to my frontend : localhost/* to my frontend
Except one path to my backend API : localhost/v1/* to my backend

I secure my database container (mongodb) by allowing only communication with my backend

Here is my docker-compose.yml (I'm only using this)

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  frontend:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/test/frontend
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ../frontend/.
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web    
    networks:
      - traefik-network

  backend:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/test/backend
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ../backend/.
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=PathPrefix(`/v1`)
      - traefik.http.routers.backend.service=backend
      - traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000
    command: yarn start
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/backend
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ../backend/.:/usr/src/backend
    networks:
      - traefik-network
      - backend-network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.2.1-bionic
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - backend-network

volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  backend-network:
  traefik-network:
```

**The problem is...**

If the frontend (backend and traefik too) is turned on

- the paths to localhost/* work (this is what I want),
- but the paths to localhost/v1/* don't work **(Problem here!).**

If the frontend is turned off but traefik and backend is turned on

- the paths to localhost/* don't work (of course, that's right),
- but the paths to localhost/v1/* work (of course, this is what I want).

I've tried a lot of solutions but nothing seems to work the way I want it to.
What did I misunderstand?

Thanks for helping,
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this label to my containers

`traefik.docker.network=traefik-network`

It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following labels to the backend service

```
- "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`servicex.me`) && Path(`/v1`)"
```

and frontend

```
- traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`servicex.me`)
```

you also need to add this line to your `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 servicex.me
```

and make sure that you stop and start the services

Complete Example

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  frontend:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/test/frontend
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ../frontend/.
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`servicex.me`)
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.service=frontend
      - traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    networks:
      - traefik-network

  backend:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/test/backend
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ../backend/.
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`servicex.me`) && Path(`/v1`)"
      - traefik.http.routers.backend.service=backend
      - traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000
    command: yarn start
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/backend
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ../backend/.:/usr/src/backend
    networks:
      - traefik-network
      - backend-network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.2.1-bionic
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - backend-network

volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  backend-network:
  traefik-network:
```

BTW, why do you need both traefik and nginx (Both are doing the same job), it would be better if you can replace one with another.

Comment: Thanks for helping! It doesn't work, `localhost/v1` send me to frontend. Nginx is only used to serve my angular application. I didn't want to mix reverse proxy in the same container as my application. Am I wrong ?

Comment: can you share the screenshot from the admin interface of traefik (the one with the created rules) ?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/rxhh84H/test.png Is this what you need?

Comment: yes, that is, from the screenshot it configs seems to be good.  Maybe you can use another domain other than localhost. I updated the answer for this change

Comment: One more note, it is important to have the double quotation on this line  - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`servicex.me`) && Path(`/v1`)"

Comment: I tried to use another domain as you said. It's doing the same as before. Yes, it is important to have the double quotation because traefik is angry without them `error while parsing rule Host(servicex.me): servicex.me is not defined`

Comment: from the screen shorts, I see there is no space around ` && `. did you also removed that space from the configs?

Comment: Yes I did, it's equivalent